# python pyqt multiple classes

Tags: python, class, authentication, pyqt

I am writing a program where I have do the following.

1. Get User Credentials using a Dialog Box
2. If successful Launch another application, if Unsuccessful prompt again for credentials. 
   I am implementing this using two classes called x_LoginForm and x_Application
   The code is as follows
   class x_LoginForm(QDialog)
   Elements in Class
3. QLineEdit to get Username
4. QLineEdit to get Password
5. QPushbutton to Cancel
6. QPushbutton to Login

If Login is successful, I will set a flag main_window_flag to 1
class x_Application()

This class will Launch a new application and provide control to the user.
The object of this class will be instantiated if the flag main_window_flag is set to 1

```
main_window_flag=0
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = x_LoginForm()
    form.show()
    if main_window_flag == 1:
        window = x_Application()
        window.show() 
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

in the class x_LoginForm 
when I have validated I want to pass the control back to main, and instantiate an object of the x_Application class. 
to exit from the class x_LoginForm, If I issue self.close - the entire program gets closed.

Comment: What I am thinking you are asking, is why doesn't the code in the `if` block get executed?

Comment: yes. I am asking that as well how do I get the code in the if block to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that `form.show()` returns immediately and your program does the `if` check then which is likely evaluating to `False` since you have `main_window_flag=0` if you change `form.show()` to `form.exec_()` it will wait until the form closes and then proceed with the code. Read here for more about [modal dialogs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#return-value-modal-dialogs).

Comment: Thanks busfault. the form.exec_() solves my problem partially.
now the if block is executed, and the main application is launched. It starts erroring with this

QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected

Let me explain the scenario better, 
There is an existing application which is written in python and pyqt and works fine
I am writing a wrapper application on top to get user credentails, and if they are correct, then launching the main application.

Comment: is `x_Application` a `QApplication`?

Comment: Yes, it is a QApplication

Comment: hm. ok. I don't think you can have two instances of `QApplication`.  I'm surprised that it is working. can you add at least some of the `x_Application` code especially the class definition, `__init__()` and `show()`? and the error messages you are seeing to your original post?

Comment: after the form.exec_(). I added a form.close() and then the if block. which works.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I have now found the solution.